# How to implement event loop with QRunnable?

Tags: c++, qt

It seems `QThreadPool` goes hand in hand with `QRunnable`.
Is there any way to implement an event loop with `QRunnable`? Or can I have event-looped threads in `QThreadPool`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried creating a http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html object in your QRunnable and calling `exec()` on it in the `run()` method?